# How can I learn how to implement a contact form on a live website?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Basically, as a beginning web developer, I have found myself a little over my head. I am creating a web site using Bootstrap 3 for a friend's business and can handle everything so far except creating a web form which allows visitors to submit information about interest in making an appointment.

As I dive in, I see PHP may be involved. My web host (ASmallOrange) includes a tool called Form Tools (http://www.formtools.org/). While I have no trouble using the Bootstrap elements to create the look of the form, how do I make it work on a live site?

Comment: Google for 'PHP contact form'. You will get tons of working scripts. You can easily learn from them.

Comment: I did and was hoping for a little more basic tutorial. I used FormSpree, but am still looking to learn a little PHP and see about doing one myself. Thanks!

Comment: Well, then learn PHP first. There are lots of basic tutorials there. I find `w3schools` good to learn the basics. This is a place where people post questions to find answers to a specific problem. Not to learn a completely new programming language. Happy Learning!

Answer (score 1):

An easy to install/use/modify PHP script can be found [here](http://wistudat.be/contact/index.php?lang=en): 
Included: Verification code (captcha), anti exploits injection, language files and settings.

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I used something similar and a little more basic, FormSpree. It is very basic but all we need for now. I'm looking into what you provided and may use it to learn more advanced ways of implementing what FromSpree does for me.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need a contact form that just sends mail....

If so, consider leveraging the Mandrill service which is free for up to 12,000 emails per month.

**Sample Form (Alter to meet your needs)**

```
<h1>Contact</h1>
<br />

<div id="ContactMessageSentAlert" class="alert alert-success">
    You're message has been sent.  
</div>

<form role="form" id="ContactMessageForm">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="FirstName" class="sr-only legacy-label">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="FirstName" name="FirstName" maxlength="255" class="form-control" placeholder="First Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">    
        <label for="LastName" class="sr-only legacy-label">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="LastName" name="LastName" maxlength="255" class="form-control" placeholder="Last Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="EmailAddress" class="sr-only legacy-label">Email Address</label>
        <input type="email" id="EmailAddress" name="EmailAddress" maxlength="255" class="form-control" placeholder="Email Address" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">    
        <label for="TwitterUsername" class="sr-only legacy-label">Twitter Username</label>
        <input type="text" id="TwitterUsername" name="TwitterUsername" maxlength="16" class="form-control" placeholder="Twitter Username" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Subject" class="sr-only legacy-label">Subject</label>
        <input type="text" id="Subject" name="Subject" maxlength="255" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="Message" class="sr-only legacy-label">Message</label>
        <textarea id="Message" name="Message" rows="5" class="form-control" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="ContactMessageSendButton">Send</button>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/mail.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () { 
        $('#ContactMessageSentAlert').hide();
        $('#ContactMessageForm').show();

        $.validator.addMethod('twitterUsername', function(value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || /^(@?[a-zA-Z0-9\_]{1,15})$/.test(value);
        }, 'Invalid');

        var validator = $('#ContactMessageForm').validate({
            errorElement: 'div',
            rules: {
                FirstName: {required: true},
                LastName: {required: true},
                EmailAddress: {required: true, email: true},
                TwitterUsername: {twitterUsername: true},
                Subject: {required: true},
                Message: {required: true}
            },
            messages: {
                FirstName: {required: 'Please enter your first name.'},
                LastName: {required: 'Please enter your last name.'},
                EmailAddress: {required: 'Please enter your email address.', email: 'Please enter a valid email address.'},
                TwitterUsername: {twitterUsername: 'Please enter a valid Twitter username.'},
                Subject: {required: 'Please enter a subject.'},
                Message: {required: 'Please enter a message.'}
            },
            errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
                $(error).insertBefore($(element));
            },
            highlight: function(element, errorClass) {              
                $(element).parent('div').addClass('has-error');
            },          
            unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                $(element).parent('div').removeClass('has-error');
            },
            onfocusout: false,
            invalidHandler: function(event, validator){
                setTimeout(function(){
                    $('input:text').blur();
                    $('textarea').blur();
                    // Pseudo of input:email is not recognized by jQuery yet, so have to target the email fields individually.
                    $('#EmailAddress').blur();
                }, 10);
            }
        });     
    });
</script>
```

**/scripts/mail.js file:**

```
function sendMail(sender, senderName, recipient, subject, message) {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'https://mandrillapp.com/api/1.0/messages/send.json',  
        data: {
            /* Confirm API key before use! */
            'key': 'YOURAPICODE', 
            'message': {
                'from_email': 'INFO@YOURDOMAIN.COM',
                'from_name': senderName,
                "headers": {"Reply-To": sender},
                'to': [{'email': recipient, 'type': 'to'}],
                'autotext': 'true',
                'subject': subject,
                'html': message
            }
            }
    })
};


/* Assign an OnClick function to items in the "Send" button */
$('#ContactMessageSendButton').click(function(e) {
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var form = $('#ContactMessageForm');
        form.validate();
        if (form.valid() === true) {
            var sender = $.trim($('#EmailAddress').val());
            var senderName = $.trim($('#FirstName').val()) + ' ' + $.trim($('#LastName').val());
            var recipient = 'INFO@YOURDOMAIN.COM';
            var subject = $.trim($('#Subject').val());
            var message = $.trim($('#Message').val()).replace(/\n/g, '<br />') + '<br />' + $.trim($('#TwitterUsername').val());
            sendMail(sender, senderName, recipient, subject, message);
            $('#ContactMessageSentAlert').show();
            $('#ContactMessageForm').hide();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: My sample above requires jQuery.Validate plugin: http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js

Comment: Thanks so much for this. I used something similar and a little more basic, FormSpree. It is very basic but all we need for now.